# Downloading git blobs in a blobless clone without checking out

Tags: git

With the `--filter=blob:none` flag, the git clone command will download all commits and trees, and only download blobs on demand with a git checkout.

For example

```bash
# clone
git clone --filter=blob:none --bare https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git
# checkout
git --git-dir=linux.git --work-tree=path/to/work/tree checkout --force
```

However, I want to download the blobs for a branch without the checkout process, as I do not need a working tree and the checkout process causes a lot of file writing which slows down the process.

How can I download all the blobs needed for a branch without using `git checkout`?